# Mobile css reverts back to desktop version of site on smartphone

Tags: html, css

I'm using a basic method of "mobilizing" my desktop site using different style sheets. At the top of every page of my site, I have this:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://scoresquare.net/css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="Screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://scoresquare.net/css/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="handheld" />
```

Whenever a user logs into my site from a smartphone, it goes to the home page [index.php] which also has the abovementioned code at the top. There are eight buttons on the home page, and whichever choice the user makes, the site properly displays the mobile version on their smartphone.

HOWEVER, whenever the user decides to return to the home page via a button on any other page, index.php displays in the DESKTOP version on their smartphone. In other words, index.php displays properly the first time on a smartphone, but not the second (and every subsequent) time.

If the user just hits the BACK button on his smartphone browser to get back to the home page, index.php displays the proper mobile format.

FWIW, each home page button involves my program querying a SQL database and returning data (which works just fine). Does this somehow reset the style sheet functionality?

If it matters, mymobile.css looks like this:

```
/* mobile styles */
@media handheld {

html, body {
    font: 12px/15px sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    }
#sidebar, #footer {
    display: none;
    }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
    }
#content img { 
    max-width: 250px;
    }
.center {
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align: center;
    }
a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #0000CC;
    }
a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #660066;
    }
    }
/* iPad [portrait + landscape] */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
.selector-01 { margin: 10px; }
.selector-02 { margin: 10px; }
.selector-03 { margin: 10px; }
    }
 /* iPhone [portrait + landscape] */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
.selector-01 { margin: 10px; }
.selector-02 { margin: 10px; }
.selector-03 { margin: 10px; }
}
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried other media queries? Something like `media="only screen and (max-device-width:480px)"`?

Comment: I think your media type isn't valid ("handheld"). Try Caleb's suggestion and I feel like it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that it works on the first load!

The [valid media types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Media_types) are "all," "print," "screen," and "speech." In current practice, "screen" is often considered equivalent to "all", and the type is simply left out (leaving media type specification for cases of print-only and screen reader-only styles).

Media queries in a linked stylesheet will look something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />
```

(that was copied from this [write-up of how to use media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries))

In your case, the final markup will be similar to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://scoresquare.net/css/screen.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://scoresquare.net/css/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="(max-width: 400px)" />
```

(I don't know what width you're using as a "handheld" breakpoint, so I just used 400px. CSS-Tricks' [Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) is one good reference for `max-width` mobile break points… it's rare that you'd bother targeting a specific device, but for example this shows you that a breakpoint at 800px will catch the most popular tablets)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, but I'm afraid this doesn't work. It still defaults back to a desktop version on my smartphone (tho it works fine on my tablet)

Feel free to visit the main site on your own smartphone and see for yourself (you must sign up for an account, but just enter a dummy email address). Still baffled.

Comment: Strange. Is it possible it's a different page? Maybe you have an extra copy of the main page, and you're linking to the wrong one (that's actually happened to me before). No offense but browser malware has slipped through my defenses before so I'm a little wary of signing up for your site.

Comment: Completely understand about signing up for the site. I only have a single index.php.  Could it have anything to do with the way I link back to index.php? [button vs. input, onclick vs. a href only, etc.?]

Comment: No, a page is a page regardless of how you got there. Did you double check to the see that the loading source has the fixed `<link>`s? Maybe the old version is cached and still being used

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean by "loading source"? And how would I change/clear the cached version?